# Compare the entire data frame to the same month in the reference year

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe below, I want to set the compare year to i.e. 2018. and calculate the value difference in i.e. 2023-06-01 versus 2018-06-01

Need to grab the month and day in the Date column, then calculate the BenchDiff by subtracting to the value at the same month, day but year is changed to 2018?

my dataframe looks like this

| Date | GEO | Variable | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-06-01 | USA | GDP | 100 |
| 2018-06-01 | USA | GDP | 400 |
| 2019-06-01 | USA | GDP | 600 |
| 2017-07-01 | USA | GDP | 5 |
| 2018-07-01 | USA | GDP | 7 |
| 2019-07-01 | USA | GDP | 10 |

the end result should be

| Date | GEO | Variable | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-06-01 | USA | GDP | 100 |
| 2018-06-01 | USA | GDP | 400 |
| 2019-06-01 | USA | GDP | 600 |
| 2017-07-01 | USA | GDP | 5 |
| 2018-07-01 | USA | GDP | 7 |
| 2019-07-01 | USA | GDP | 10 |
| 2019-06-01 | USA | BenchDiff | -300 |
| 2017-06-01 | USA | BenchDiff | 0 |
| 2018-06-01 | USA | BenchDiff | -00 |
| 2019-06-01 | USA | BenchDiff | -300 |
| 2017-07-01 | USA | BenchDiff | -2 |
| 2018-07-01 | USA | BenchDiff | 0 |
| 2019-07-01 | USA | BenchDiff | 3 |

I can do it if it's set a specific date, but I can't get it roll it

```r
df %>%
  group_by(GEO, Variable) %>%
  mutate(BenchDiff = Value - Value[match(compare_date, Date)])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `tidyr::pivot_longer()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(month = substr(Date, 6, 7)) %>%
  mutate(BenchDiff = Value - Value[match("2018", substr(Date, 1, 4))]) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-month) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(Value, BenchDiff), cols_vary = "slowest")

# # A tibble: 12 × 5
#    Date       GEO   Variable name      value
#    <chr>      <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <int>
#  1 2017-06-01 USA   GDP      Value       100
#  2 2018-06-01 USA   GDP      Value       400
#  3 2019-06-01 USA   GDP      Value       600
#  4 2017-07-01 USA   GDP      Value         5
#  5 2018-07-01 USA   GDP      Value         7
#  6 2019-07-01 USA   GDP      Value        10
#  7 2017-06-01 USA   GDP      BenchDiff  -300
#  8 2018-06-01 USA   GDP      BenchDiff     0
#  9 2019-06-01 USA   GDP      BenchDiff   200
# 10 2017-07-01 USA   GDP      BenchDiff    -2
# 11 2018-07-01 USA   GDP      BenchDiff     0
# 12 2019-07-01 USA   GDP      BenchDiff     3
```

Comment: sorry amended question. the bench date changes, only the year is staying the same.  so this wont' work.

Comment: @user15032839 see my update! Is that what you want?

Comment: I think we are close.  I need to grab the month and day in the Date column, then calculate the BenchDiff by subtracting to the value at the same month, date but year is changed to 2018?